# Verificar se algum elemento está sendo clicado com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Abstraindo:
Não manjo de Javascript mas sei que com ele consigo fazer o que quero. Gostaria de saber como verifico se um input está sendo clicado, e quando ele for, queria adicionar classes css a outros elementos da página.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Eu achei algo que pode te ajuda: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Serà um unico campo? Ou varios?

Comment: Eu quero clicar no input e add um background no site

Comment: Exemplo: `<input type="number" onclick="myFunction()">`

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara de mais detalhes do que pretende mais exatamente.

Comment: Eu quero especificamente o efeito que ocorre quando clica-se na bara de pesquisa do https://www.shoptime.com.br/ em que se escurece o fundo

Comment: Usar a chamada de funcao direto do html <input onchange="funcao()"> nao é a mais adequada. O mais adequado é voce fazer o javascript esperar evento objeto.onclick = function(){ seu codigo};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode usar um pseudo elemento na `div` que tem um `input` dentro, assim com o `focus-within` vc mostra ou não o pseudo elemento que cobre o site inteiro por baixo. Nem precisa de JS para isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
div:focus-within::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1
}
.foca {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pesquisa">
  <input class="foca" type="text">
</div>


<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sequi architecto fugiat, voluptas deleniti debitis harum, rem est voluptates minima facere neque quis ullam asperiores ab necessitatibus nostrum porro velit!
</div>
```